# Number format Exception on JSP Page with decimal values

Tags: java, jsp, number-formatting

[image]I am using the below code on my JSP page to show cost formatted by comma,

```
   <%      java.util.Locale locale =  java.util.Locale.US;
  java.text.NumberFormat numberFormatter =       java.text.NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);

    String specialChars = "..";

   Double d= Double.valueOf(cost);
   int cnvCost = d.intValue();

  %>


  <input id="test" class="form-control"  value="<%=numberFormatter.format(cnvCost) %>"   type="text" />
```

But for decimal values it is throwing an exception that java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "34876.98"

Appreciate any help in resolving this issue.

Comment: It doesn't for me. Are you sure the exception did not happen elsewhere?

Comment: What's the expected output in your case? `34,876`?? If so it's working good.

Comment: Yes am expecting an output 34,876

Answer (score -1):

```
below code display result as you want.
<%
        java.util.Locale locale = java.util.Locale.US;
        java.text.NumberFormat numberFormatter = java.text.NumberFormat
                .getNumberInstance(locale);

        String specialChars = "..";
        String cost="34876.98";
        Double d = Double.valueOf(cost);
        int cnvCost = d.intValue();
    %>


    <input id="test" class="form-control"
        value="<%=numberFormatter.format(cnvCost)%>" type="text" />
```

Comment: Hi Folks, Thank you for all your help, It is working now . I was using Integer.parseInt(cost) before this code which caused the error.